# Qt - H.264 video streaming using FFmpeg libraries

Tags: qt, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264

I am trying to get my IP camera stream in my Qt Widget application. First, I connect to UDP port of IP camera. IP camera is streaming H.264 encoded video. After socket is bound, on each `readyRead()` signal, I am filling the buffer with received datagrams in order to get a full frame.

Variable initialization:

```
AVCodec *codec;
AVCodecContext *codecCtx;
AVFrame *frame;
AVPacket packet;
this->buffer.clear();
this->socket = new QUdpSocket(this);

QObject::connect(this->socket, &QUdpSocket::connected, this, &H264VideoStreamer::connected);
QObject::connect(this->socket, &QUdpSocket::disconnected, this, &H264VideoStreamer::disconnected);
QObject::connect(this->socket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &H264VideoStreamer::readyRead);
QObject::connect(this->socket, &QUdpSocket::hostFound, this, &H264VideoStreamer::hostFound);
QObject::connect(this->socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
QObject::connect(this->socket, &QUdpSocket::stateChanged, this, &H264VideoStreamer::stateChanged);

avcodec_register_all();

codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
if (!codec){
   qDebug() << "Codec not found";
   return;
}

codecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
if (!codecCtx){
    qDebug() << "Could not allocate video codec context";
    return;
}

if (codec->capabilities & CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
      codecCtx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;

codecCtx->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS;

AVDictionary *dictionary = nullptr;

if (avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, &dictionary) < 0) {
    qDebug() << "Could not open codec";
    return;
}
```

Algorithm is as follows:

```
void H264VideoImageProvider::readyRead() {
    QByteArray datagram;
    datagram.resize(this->socket->pendingDatagramSize());
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;

    this->socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &sender, &senderPort);

    QByteArray rtpHeader = datagram.left(12);
    datagram.remove(0, 12);

    int nal_unit_type = datagram[0] & 0x1F;
    bool start = (datagram[1] & 0x80) != 0;

    int seqNo = rtpHeader[3] & 0xFF;

    qDebug() << "H264 video decoder::readyRead()"
             << "from: " << sender.toString() << ":" << QString::number(senderPort)
             << "\n\tDatagram size: " << QString::number(datagram.size())
             << "\n\tH264 RTP header (hex): " << rtpHeader.toHex()
             << "\n\tH264 VIDEO data (hex): " << datagram.toHex();

    qDebug() << "nal_unit_type = " << nal_unit_type << " - " << getNalUnitTypeStr(nal_unit_type);
    if (start)
        qDebug() << "START";

    if (nal_unit_type == 7){
        this->sps = datagram;
        qDebug() << "Sequence parameter found = " << this->sps.toHex();
        return;
    } else if (nal_unit_type == 8){
        this->pps = datagram;
        qDebug() << "Picture parameter found = " << this->pps.toHex();
        return;
    }

    //VIDEO_FRAME
    if (start){
        if (!this->buffer.isEmpty())
            decodeBuf();

        this->buffer.clear();
        qDebug() << "Initializing new buffer...";

        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x01));

        this->buffer.append(this->sps);

        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x01));

        this->buffer.append(this->pps);

        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x00));
        this->buffer.append(char(0x01));
    }

    qDebug() << "Appending buffer data...";
    this->buffer.append(datagram);
}
```

- first 12 bytes of datagram is RTP header
- everything else is VIDEO DATA
- last 5 bits of first VIDEO DATA byte, says which NAL unit type it is. I always get one of the following 4 values (1 - coded non-IDR slice, 5 code IDR slice, 7 SPS, 8 PPS)
- 5th bit in 2nd VIDEO DATA byte says if this datagram is START data in frame
- all VIDEO DATA is stored in buffer starting with START
- once new frame arrives - START is set, it is decoded and new buffer is generated
- frame for decoding is generated like this:

  ```
   00 00 00 01
   SPS
   00 00 00 01
   PPS
   00 00 00 01
  ```

  concatenated VIDEO DATA
- decoding is made using `avcodec_decode_video2()` function from FFmpeg library

  ```
   void H264VideoStreamer::decode() {
       av_init_packet(&packet);
       av_new_packet(&packet, this->buffer.size());
       memcpy(packet.data, this->buffer.data_ptr(), this->buffer.size());
       packet.size = this->buffer.size();    
       frame = av_frame_alloc();
       if(!frame){
           qDebug() << "Could not allocate video frame";
           return;
       }
       int got_frame = 1;
       int len = avcodec_decode_video2(codecCtx, frame, &got_frame, &packet);
       if (len < 0){
           qDebug() << "Error while encoding frame.";
           return;
       }
       //if(got_frame > 0){ // got_frame is always 0
       //    qDebug() << "Data decoded: " << frame->data[0];
       //}
       char * frameData = (char *) frame->data[0];
       QByteArray decodedFrame;
       decodedFrame.setRawData(frameData, len);
       qDebug() << "Data decoded: " << decodedFrame;
       av_frame_unref(frame);
       av_free_packet(&packet);
       emit imageReceived(decodedFrame);
   }
  ```

My idea is in UI thread which receives `imageReceived` signal, convert `decodedFrame` directly in `QImage` and refresh it once new frame is decoded and sent to UI.

Is this good approach for decoding H.264 stream? I am facing following problems:

- `avcodec_decode_video2()` returns value that is the same like encoded buffer size. Is it possible that encoded and decoded date are always same size?
- `got_frame` is always 0, so it means that I never really received full frame in the result. What can be the reason? Video frame incorrectly created? Or video frame incorrectly converted from `QByteArray` to `AVframe`?
- How can I convert decoded `AVframe` back to `QByteArray`, and can it just be simply converted to `QImage`?

Comment: This statement `this->buffer.append(datagram);` looks wrong to me. If you receive UDP packets, then the order in which you receive them is not known (well, it is on a Unix socket, but not on a regular network connection). What that means is you must know the packet number and using that number where to add the UDP packet data to the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The whole process of manually rendering the frames can be left to another library. If the only purpose is a Qt GUI with live feed from the IP camera you can use libvlc library. You can find an example here: https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Qt

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to stick with FFmpeg library. Is it possible to get udp stream with libvlc?

Comment: i am not sure. I think you can, based on the comments in the link i pasted. You can check for youtself if you open VLC client and got to Media->Open network stream and paste your link there. If the stream starts then you can probably do it with libvlc as well.

Comment: Yeah, that make sense since VLC is based od libVLC. Well, thanks so far for the answers, this will be my backup plan if I don't manage to get stream with FFmpeg, still waiting for an answer.